# LocationManager is null after initialization

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity, locationmanager, android-location

I have tried to initialize the `LocationManager` and use a `Button` to get the location obtained as a `Toast` on the screen,however I find that the LocationManager is null:

/MyLocationTest﹕ Failed to initialize LocationManager

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.mylocationtest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The first line is a message that I print to `Logcat` because the `LocationManager` is null even though I initialize it like this in `onCreate`:

```
  locMan=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  //set a click listener for the button:
  btn_loc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       boolean isGPSReady,isNetworkReady;
       if(locMan==null)
       {
          Log.d("MyLocationTest", "Failed to initialize LocationManager");
       }
       isGPSReady=locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       isNetworkReady=locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
       if(!isNetworkReady && !isGPSReady)
       {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sorry,location could not be enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else if(isNetworkReady)
       {
        //the third parameter is a looper that controls where the callback happens from...
              locMan.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,locEar_network, null);
        latitude=loc.getLatitude();
        longitude=loc.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"The latitude is "+latitude+" and the longitude is "+longitude+" and the accuracy is "+loc.getAccuracy(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else if(isGPSReady)
       {
           locMan.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,locEar_gps,null);
           latitude=loc.getLatitude();
           longitude=loc.getLongitude();
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"The latitude is "+latitude+" and the longitude is "+longitude+ "and the accuracy is "+loc.getAccuracy(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

     }
  });
```

In my manifest,I have used the following to ensure that API level 9 is the minSDKVersion for `requestSingleUpdate` and the app is permitted access to fine location:

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mylocationtest" >m
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
          android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

## EDIT:

[The entire class is here as a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/t7NF6XnN)

How can I ensure that the LocationManager is never null?

Comment: You do not show the code where "loc"  (from which you call loc.getLatitude() )is initialised. My guess is that is what's null. You probably need to wait for onLocationChanged() to run.

Comment: what does your `this` refers to ?

Comment: this is within `onCreate` so it refers to the `Activity`

Comment: Why do you use `locMan=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);` instead of `locMan=(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`?

Comment: @NickT I use LocationListener's onLocationChanged to update loc which is an instance of Location type

Comment: @nikis because the second one gave me the same problem....either is correct,I believe

Comment: Yes, and until that runs loc will be null. If you click the button before that, you will get the NPE. Why don't you check it with a Toast triggered by if (loc == null)?

Comment: You can remove `this`

Answer (score 1):

If Location manager tries to get a location from the network provider, some times there might not be a location available from the network provider or it may require some time to get the location in these cases you might get a null.

Location manager might also get null if the gps coudnt find any location most probably inside a building

Comment: LocationManager is null if you are only using GPS and are indoors,then network must be available as I am connected to a Wifi network which must provide information about my location

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting up a log if the LocationManager is null. You should avoid accessing it when it's null also. Modify you code like this.

```
   boolean isGPSReady,isNetworkReady;
   if(locMan==null)
   {
      Log.d("MyLocationTest", "Failed to initialize LocationManager");
   }
   else{
       isGPSReady=locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       isNetworkReady=locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

       if(!isNetworkReady && !isGPSReady)
       {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sorry,location could not be enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else if(isNetworkReady)
       {
            //the third parameter is a looper that controls where the callback happens from...
            locMan.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,locEar_network, null);
            latitude=loc.getLatitude();
            longitude=loc.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"The latitude is "+latitude+" and the longitude is "+longitude+" and the accuracy is "+loc.getAccuracy(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else if(isGPSReady)
       {
           locMan.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,locEar_gps,null);
           latitude=loc.getLatitude();
           longitude=loc.getLongitude();
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"The latitude is "+latitude+" and the longitude is "+longitude+ "and the accuracy is "+loc.getAccuracy(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
```

One more thing, are you using a GPS enabled device to test this? If you want more information [refer this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html).

Try adding these two permissions also to AndroidManifest.xml file.

INTERNET

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Comment: I am testing on my phone which is Location enabled,the other question is that I am indoors and connected to Wifi so,network should definitely have info regarding my location

Comment: Why use the Internet permission??

Comment: LocationManager is still null,is it better to use the Google Location service instead??

Comment: It's strange, I have done an application using this approach. What about these two lines, isGPSReady=locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       isNetworkReady=locMan.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); Are you getting false?

Comment: I wish,that would have made me happy too,but I cannot use `locMan` at all,it throws a `NullPointerException` when trying to obtain `isGpsReady`

Comment: On a different device,I get false for both the values,so this is a device specific problem...so I guess we can close it down as not a real question??